# Ubuntu Desktop Screen res more than 1366x768

Tags: display, display-resolution

I have just installed Ubuntu desktop on my Lenovo G500 Laptop and cant get it's res over 1366x768

`xrandr` outputs:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1968, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+344+1200 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00
```

How can i solve this?

- Connecting an other big dell screen does display this kind of resolution)
- I didn't find any drivers for my graphic card..

Answer (score 0):

According to [the manufacturers documentation](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/emea/content/pdf/Essential/GSeries/en/essential-g500-datasheet.pdf) 1366x768 is the max resolution. Any resolution that is higher would not be supported by your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Drivers for your Intel Graphics are already installed and working as they are open source and included by default in Ubuntu.

Lenovo G500 came with 1366x768 native resolution (it cannot be exceeded in that particular screen).

Other external displays may support higher resolutions - the graphics chipset certainly support much more - but whether or not you can set them to their native resolution (recommended) depends on your screen settings. Mirroring limits the resolution to the lower one which in this case is the native resolution of the internal display.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an additional troubleshooting item:
In my case, the problem was a loosely connected vga cable.
For some reason the Monitor Settings could recognize my monitor only as VGA1 and lower resolutions. I struggled for a while with drivers and xrandr modes - it failed.
After I connected it correctly the system could recognize my monitor brand and its maximum resolution.